# How to display NativeImage in Electron

Tags: electron

I have an Electron `WebView`. I want to take a screenshot of its content and display it somewhere in my application.

I have tried using the [`webview.capturePage`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewcapturepagerect-callback) method, which returns a [Native Image](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#class-nativeimage).

How can I add that image to the DOM and thus display it on my app? I'm unsure how to convert it.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you share your code?

Comment: Using the [image.toDataURL](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#imagetodataurloptions) method is possibly the way to go. This [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8FaLDEn3zg) explains how, among other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`image.toDataURL`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#imagetodataurloptions) for this purpose (as @Mikaeru suggested) An example could be

```
<html>
  <body>
    <webview id="view" src="https://www.github.com/" style="width:320px; height:240px">
    </webview>
    <button id="capture">Capture</button>
    <img id="show" src="" />
    <script>
      const wv = document.getElementById('view')
      const b = document.getElementById('capture')
      const i = document.getElementById('show')
      b.addEventListener('click', () => {
        wv.capturePage((img) => {
          i.src = img.toDataURL()
        })
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```